# IN(1, 2...n) query optimization

Tags: sql, optimization, mysql

As far as I know, mysql doesn't use index if using IN(1, 2...n) queries. Am I wrong? Or is there anything I could do to make mysql use it? I don't mean IN() subquery optimization, because this is clearly explained in the manual.

Example (assuming there is an index on all fields, named index_abc):

`WHERE a = 1 AND b = 2 AND c = 3` - then it uses index_abc

`WHERE a = 2 AND b IN (2, 4, 5) AND C = 3` - then it doesn't

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: EXPLAIN is your friend: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html

Comment: If I didn't use explain, how could I write with confidence about situations when it uses indexes and when it doesn't... From learning manual by heart? Don't be silly. Logic is also your friend.

Comment: Can you post up the results of the EXPLAIN for the two queries for anyone who is interested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What determines where the values in your `IN` expression come from?  Odds are it's either user input, or something that *should* be in a table somewhere.  Examples of things that should be in a table include hard-coded lookup values.  Even user input could first be inserted in a table somewhere.  Then you can use a `JOIN` rather than an `IN` and your indexes will work just fine.

Comment: Those values are evaluated in application. But surely it's a way - to figure out if it's possible to evaluate them using sql. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

[here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-indexes.html) are described all cases when MySQL can use indexes. i didn't see IN there. rewrite your query to `(b = 2 OR b = 4 OR b = 5) AND c = 3` that should make mysql to use index. i think it is just because mysql is not smart enough :)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Joel.

Try to avoid IN statements where possible. (In most cases they can be replaced by JOINS.) Using IN statements is a known performance drawback. Also be aware that IN statements have a maximum number of allowed members on (most?) databases.

Answer (score 0):

Posting your Explain would really help. Try adding
FORCE KEY(keyname) into your query as see if it fixed your issue.